# Matters in plugin systems (PHP)

Tags: php, plugins

I made a plugin system with help of the WP idea. But there are some points that I can't realize what should user do at that moments for example if a user wrote a plugin for his self and the functions or methods name was same as the other plugins so what should he do after that ?. Of course I explained that when the function doesn't exist and use your plugin name at first of every function then define it in my plugin system definition.

```
if ( ! function_exists ( plugin_... ) ) {
  function plugin_... () {

  }
}
```

any idea ?

BTW is pure the taxonomy and concept of WP plugin system ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When designing a plugin system, the plugins really should be classes. Then the only possible name conflict is the class name.

As an alternative, you can use a naming convention that all plugin functions should have a prefix. This is sort of accomplishing the same thing as classes, but it's repetitive.

Comment: You know, Because I chooses the way of WP, I saw there was functions out of classes which they can run next to another function from another plugin. But I think you mentioned a good point, I should make plugin base class  for ever one of them and complex their functions and methods in one class.

Answer (score 1):

PHP Namespaces are exactly for this.http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: Thanks but I should keep it in my mind that the whole system should be easy to learn and build for every one. I don't think any plugin builder beginner would like those things. But thanks. I worked with them before.